Why are certain badges counted from UTC than your local timezone
For badges like Enthusiast and Fanatic, why are they counted by UTC time rather than my local timezone (PST)? Is it because Stack Exchange was made where UTC is used (e.g. London)? Can I change that setting somewhere, if it is possible?

GMT is what's used in London. UMT is used everywhere. The primary servers are in New York, the secondary ones in Oregon (I think).

Everything is based on a unified timezone, because it makes no sense to adjust (especially the badge) processes for individual user location.

@W.O. what is UMT? is it UTC?

It's a medical condition I have related to bad typing. @SnappyRiffs ;)

I think everything SE's internally UTC?

Even though there servers are not in UTC timezone? that to me does not make sense. It should be EST (UTC-5) or something like that

This seems similar: Change the definition of a "day" to be localized for users. (But rather old.) There is also this FAQ post: What is an SE "day"? When does each day start? Some of the questions linked there might be related, too.

The reason why is explained in this answer to the declined feature request Change the definition of a "day" to be localized for users.

Stack Exchange operates around the world, why would they not use the timezone that allows everybody to easily work out Tue offset, instead of some silly arbitrary other place's timezone?
